# How do I create parallel text aligned by paragraph?

Tags: parallel, parallel-texts

I would like to create parallel text in multiple languages. With some success, I have tried some existing packages to do that.

However, one thing I found very difficult is to align each paragraph but use different font sizes and (thus) independent line spacing for each language. This would be useful for languages where the texts are very different in length (for example Chinese and English).

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Could you tell which packages you have already tried? Would something like a long table, where you type each paragraph into a cell, be useful to you?

Comment: I have used parallel and ledpar (should have included in original q).

Comment: Just edit your question to say that. If you can show some sample code that you've tried, that would be even better. Certainly a good question, regardless.

Comment: Is it ok to have page breaks only between paragraphs? In that case I'd try to define a macro that simply places two `\parbox` things side by side, with appropriate fonts, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used [parcolumns](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) package for something similar.

Comment: I noticed that this was mentioned in another comment as well. This seems like a good choice and I will try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [multicolpar](http://az.ctan.org/pkg/multicolpar)? I'm quite happy with it.

This arrangement is useful when displaying a translated document as a "parallel text". The number of columns to be used is controlled by a parameter of the multicolpar environment.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 the packages [reledpar](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledpar)
**together** with [reledmac](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) worked well. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                \lipsum[1]
                \pend
                \pstart
                \lipsum[2]
                \pend
                \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
                \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                \lipsum[3]
                \pend
                \pstart
                \lipsum[4]
                \pend
                \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

If you need the parallel text to be on the same page in two columns, replace
`\begin{pages}`, `\end{pages}` and `\Pages` with
`\begin{pairs}`, `\end{pairs}` and `\Columns`,
respectively.