# Multicolumn listing for comparison in LaTeX

Tags: listings, positioning

I have some C code that I want to insert in a LaTeX document using a listing. I also want to display its translation to assembly code. I don't know how to display those two kind of codes in a multicolumn view, so to give the reader the possibility to make a quick comparison between C code and assembly code. I don't need to have the lines of C aligned with their correspondent assembly instructions since I think this is not going to be easy to do. What I need is just to show the two codes side by side. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code can be displayed using the `listings` package. The side by side effect I would do using two `minipages` as shown below. In general you have to be careful because the listings are verbatim material and don't work inside the arguments of other macros. (Using saveboxes helps here)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\par\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,frame=lrtb]
   int function test(int a) {
         return a;
   }
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=lrtb]
   TEST:
       goto SOMEWHERE
\end{lstlisting}%
\end{minipage}%

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 11):

You may try [parcolumns](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) package.

*See also other question: [Of parallel texts, lists and display equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-do-i-create-parallel-text-aligned-by-paragraph).*

#### Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{beramono}
\usepackage{pifont,calc,xcolor}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{verylightgray}{gray}{0.85}
\newlength\lsthorizontalpadding
\setlength\lsthorizontalpadding{3pt}
\newcommand*\lstnumberstyle{\ttfamily\scriptsize}
\newlength\lstnumbersep
\setlength\lstnumbersep{10pt}
\newlength\lstnumberwidth
\setlength\lstnumberwidth{\widthof{\lstnumberstyle00}+\lstnumbersep+\lsthorizontalpadding}
\lstset{
    ,basicstyle=\ttfamily%
    ,breaklines=true%
    ,tabsize=4%
    ,showstringspaces=false%
    ,numbers=left%
    ,numbersep=\lstnumbersep%
    ,numberstyle=\lstnumberstyle%
    ,framesep=0pt%
    ,xleftmargin=\lstnumberwidth%
    ,framexleftmargin=\lsthorizontalpadding%
    ,xrightmargin=\lsthorizontalpadding%
    ,framexrightmargin=\lsthorizontalpadding%
    ,backgroundcolor=\color{verylightgray}%
    ,postbreak=\ding{229}\space%
}
%% far from complete list of gasm-specific keywords and instructions in AT&T syntax
\lstdefinelanguage[x86gasm]{Assembler}[x86masm]{Assembler}{%
    ,morekeywords={rax,rbx,rcx,rdx,rip,rdi,rsi,rsp,subq,decl,movq,movl,xorl,imull,popq}%
    ,morekeywords=[2]{.file,.section,.string,.text,.globl,.cfi_startproc,.cfi_def_cfa_offset,.cfi_endproc,.size,.ident}%
}
\lstnewenvironment{ccol}[1][]{\lstset{language=c,#1}}{}
\lstnewenvironment{acol}[1][]{\lstset{language=[x86gasm]Assembler,#1}}{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\texttt{gcc} on \texttt{text.c} file (left side) [\texttt{gcc -S -Os text.c}] gives following assembler code (right side):
\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk[1]{\begin{ccol}
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int t;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    t = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d^2 = %d\n", t, t * t);

    return 0;
}
\end{ccol}}
\colchunk[2]{\begin{acol}
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Not enough arguments!\n"
.LC1:
    .string "%d^2 = %d\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    decl    %edi
    jg  .L2
    movq    stderr(%rip), %rsi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    call    fputs
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    movq    8(%rsi), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    atoi
    movl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC1, %edi
    imull   %eax, %edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    call    printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L3:
    popq    %rdx
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
\end{acol}}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code you provided is very complete, thanks.